# Is the filter generated by $A$-generic sets S1-prime?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Let $\mathfrak U$ be a monster model.

Let $A\subseteq\mathfrak U$ be a small set of parameters.

A set $\mathfrak D\subseteq\mathfrak U^{|x|}$ is *$A$-generic* if finitely many translations of $\mathfrak D$ under Aut$(\mathfrak U/A)$ cover $\mathfrak U^{|x|}$.

Let $\mu$ be the filter generated by the set $\{\mathfrak D\subseteq \mathfrak U^{|x|}:$ definable (with parameters) and $A$-generic$\}$.

I would like to know if the following holds:

> For every $A$-indiscernibles sequence $(\mathfrak D_i:i<\omega)$ of definable subsets of $\mathfrak U^{|x|}$ if $\mathfrak D_0\cup\mathfrak D_1\in\mu$ then $\mathfrak D_0\in\mu$.

In other words, I am asking if $μ$ is S1 prime.
The answer is affirmative if all sets in $\mu$ are $A$-generic. But in general we only have that the sets in $\mu$ are finite intersections of $A$-generic sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\mu$ is S1 prime.

First, let me point out that your definitions are related to some standard terminology.

A formula $\varphi(x;b)$ is said to *quasi-divide* over $A$ if there are finitely many realizations $b_1,\dots,b_n$ of $\mathrm{tp}(b/A)$ such that $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \varphi(x;b_i)$ is inconsistent. Taking complements, we see that $\varphi(x;b)$ quasi-divides over $A$ if and only if $\lnot \varphi(\mathfrak{U};b)$ is $A$-generic in your sense.

A formula is said to *quasi-fork* over $A$ if it is in the ideal generated by the formulas which quasi-divide over $A$. Taking complements, we see that $\varphi(x;b)$ quasi-forks over $A$ if and only if $\lnot \varphi(\mathfrak{U};b)\in \mu$.

Now a formula quasi-forks over $A$ if and only if it is not contained in any global $A$-invariant type. I'm happy to provide a proof of this fact on request. Taking complements, we see that the definable sets in the filter $\mu$ are exactly the definable sets which contain *every* global $A$-invariant type.

Using this, it's easy to see that $\mu$ is $S_1$-prime. Even stronger, suppose $\mathfrak{D}_0$ and $\mathfrak{D}_1$ are conjugate over $A$ and $\mathfrak{D}_0\cup \mathfrak{D}_1\in \mu$. To show $\mathfrak{D}_0\in \mu$, let $p$ be a global $A$-invariant type and suppose for contradiction that $p\notin \mathfrak{D}_0$. Then by invariance $p\notin \mathfrak{D}_1$, so $p\notin \mathfrak{D}_0\cup \mathfrak{D}_1$, contradicting $\mathfrak{D}_0\cup \mathfrak{D}_1\in \mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much. B.t.w., where is the terminology quasi-divide/fork coming from?

Comment: @DomenicoZambella I believe the terminology was introduced by Chernikov and Kaplan in their paper [Forking and dividing in $\mathrm{NTP}_2$ theories](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23208231).

Comment: Another place it appears is in the recent preprint [Bi-invariant types, reliably invariant types, and the Comb Tree Property](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.08239.pdf) by James Hanson.